# Compile-time array concatenation

Tags: c

C supports concatenating constant strings at compile-time. Can I do the same for any constant array? (E.g. concatenate two char ** arrays.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically no, but you can always workaround this with the preprocessor. The trick is to define arrays without curly braces:

```
#define ARRAY_ONE "test1", "test2", "test3"
#define ARRAY_TWO "testa", "testb", "testc"
```

Now, you can join arrays in compile time with comma.
To use them, however, you will either have to sorround them with curly braces or use a macro:

```
#define ARR(...) {__VA_ARGS__}
```

You can now use a single array or any concatenation you need like so:

```
char *arr1[] = ARR(ARRAY_ONE);
char *arr2[] = ARR(ARRAY_TWO);
char *arrc1[] = ARR(ARRAY_ONE, ARRAY_TWO);
char *arrc2[] = ARR(ARRAY_ONE, ARRAY_TWO, ARRAY_ONE, ARRAY_ONE);
```

Using macros to achieve such results is bad practice, though.

Comment: Why do you claim that using macros this way is bad practice?

Comment: I basically think that using macros which alter the syntax is always bad practice, because it's very error-prone. Which doesn't mean one shouldn't use them, as that's what they're for, among other uses. Everything is good if you know what you're doing;)

Comment: Ah, so your point is that `ARR(ARRAY_ONE, ARRAY_TWO);` reads like an array of two elements while it actually has six. Such confusion is absolutely important to avoid; I recommend to add LIST as part of the identifiers to make it clear that it expands to more than one element, e.g. `char *arrc1[] = { ARRAY_ONE_LIST, ARRAY_TWO_LIST };`.

Comment: nice solution, but I get compile errors with clang - with gcc it works quite nice: https://godbolt.org/z/7KEfzzeoY

Comment: @schnedan your clang errors seem to be related to lack of constexpr keyword in your static strings, not this answer. Also your example is in C++ and this question is tagged C. You could probably come up with better solutions in C++ or avoid having to concatenate char ** arrays completely.

Comment: @MichałTrybus There is no C++ Strings in C++... if you want to initialize Strings with Content, it must be C-Strings. Plus if you want to assemble e.g. Error Messages by Product or used Configuration, utilizing Preprocessor on C-Strings is the only way I know of at compile time. If you know a possibility how do this in "pure" C++, please share. PS: Also if you have a C++ lib, which is used in an legacy C Product, you need to provide C-Strings, also there are environments where dyn. allocating std::string needs to be avoided.

Comment: @MichałTrybus but you are right... with constexpr at the strings it works https://godbolt.org/z/cGe67rPxY

Comment: @schnedan I haven't actually tried it, but I was thinking of some compile-time template metaprogramming magic when I said there are better ways in C++. But I can't be sure without testing it in reality though.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Longer short answer: String literals are indeed character arrays, but not all character arrays are string literals. The compile-time concatenation works only for string literals. No arrays have that "feature".